# replacing keys from a dictionary inside a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, replace

I have a list inside a nested dictionary

```
body = {'Ready Date': '2020-01-31T12:00:00','Shipment Line List': [{'Description': 'Test', 'Weigth': '5', 
        'Height': '4.0','Length': '2.0', 'Width': '3.0'}, {'Description': 'Test', 'Weigth': '20', 'Height': '5',
        'Length': '30', 'Width': '10']}
```

I want to iterate over the keys in the nested dictionary and replace "Weigth" with the correct spelling "Weight"
I tried this approach, but I am not getting the expected output

```
key = {"Weigth":"Weight"}
def find_replace(dict_body, dictionary):
    # is the item in the dict?
    for item in dict_body:
        # iterate by keys
        if item in dictionary.keys():
            # look up and replace
            dict_body = dict_body.replace(item, dictionary[item])
    # return updated dict
    return dict_body

a = find_replace(body,key)
print(a)
```

Comment: Side-note: Don't do `if item in dictionary.keys():`, just do `if item in dictionary:`; the former is less inefficient on Python 3 than it was on Python 2, but it's still needlessly creating unnecessary `dict_view` objects for every test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better idea in this particular case is to treat everything as a string, replace and back as a dictionary. Because if you have multiple nested keys, it might be just be easier this way in two lines of code:

```
from ast import literal_eval
body = literal_eval(str(body).replace("Weigth","Weight"))
```

This outputs:

```
{'Ready Date': '2020-01-31T12:00:00',
 'Shipment Line List': [{'Description': 'Test',
   'Height': '4.0',
   'Length': '2.0',
   'Weight': '5',
   'Width': '3.0'},
  {'Description': 'Test',
   'Height': '5',
   'Length': '30',
   'Weight': '20',
   'Width': '10'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to iterate over the keys in the nested dictionary and replace "Weigth" with the correct spelling "Weight"

something like the below

```
body = {'Ready Date': '2020-01-31T12:00:00', 'Shipment Line List': [{'Description': 'Test', 'Weigth': '5',
                                                                     'Height': '4.0', 'Length': '2.0', 'Width': '3.0'},
                                                                    {'Description': 'Test', 'Weigth': '20',
                                                                     'Height': '5',
                                                                     'Length': '30', 'Width': '10'}]}
for entry in body['Shipment Line List']:
    entry['Weight'] = entry['Weigth']
    del entry['Weigth']
print(body)
```

output

```
{'Ready Date': '2020-01-31T12:00:00', 'Shipment Line List': [{'Description': 'Test', 'Height': '4.0', 'Length': '2.0', 'Width': '3.0', 'Weight': '5'}, {'Description': 'Test', 'Height': '5', 'Length': '30', 'Width': '10', 'Weight': '20'}]}
```

Comment: You can one-line the copy and delete with: `entry['Weight'] = entry.pop('Weigth')`. Of course, this assumes the bad key is always there; if not, you probably want to catch the `KeyError` `pop` will raise for non-existent keys.